# Calculate the percentage change between two specific rows with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
         AAPL      MSFT
May       200       120
Jun       190       122
Jul       170       127
Aug       180       135
```

I want to add a new row with index name 'percChane' that calculates the perc change bwtween the first and last row (in this example May and Aug).

```
             AAPL      MSFT
    May       200       120
    Jun       190       122
    Jul       170       127
    Aug       180       135
   percChng   -10      12.5
```

Can this be done using df.pct_change()? If not, what's the most efficient way to do this? It always needs to be the first and last row.

Comment: `df.iloc[[0,-1]].pct_change(axis=0)`?

Comment: `df =  df.append(df.iloc[[0, -1]].pct_change().iloc[-1].mul(100).rename('percChng'))`

Comment: Well, since you're in a finance environment, you may also consider to take `pct_change` and `add(1)` to make it a compounding factor, and just multiply cumulatively`df.pct_change().add(1).cumprod().sub(1)` (but i'd definitely `i.loc[[0,-1]]` ;} )

Comment: @ScottBoston Thought it was a duplicate at first, but didn't find any target so added it as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pick out the rows you want to calculate the % change for, then calculate it yourself:

```
s, e = df.iloc[0], df.iloc[-1]
df = df.append(((e - s) / s * 100).rename('percChng'))
df
           AAPL   MSFT
May       200.0  120.0
Jun       190.0  122.0
Jul       170.0  127.0
Aug       180.0  135.0
percChng  -10.0   12.5
```

---

Alternatively, you can call `pct_change` to have pandas do it for you:

```
df = df.append(df.iloc[[0, -1]].pct_change().iloc[-1].mul(100).rename('percChng'))
df
           AAPL   MSFT
May       200.0  120.0
Jun       190.0  122.0
Jul       170.0  127.0
Aug       180.0  135.0
percChng  -10.0   12.5
```